# How to attack a specific computer on a remote network?

Tags: ip, metasploit, nat

In a situation where I know the victim's public ip of their router, how does an attacker attack a specific computer in that network using something like metasploit? Because when using metasploit in the target address you either put the local ip of the victim if your attacking over LAN, or the public ip, but if more than one computer is connected to that public ip how do I attack a specific one?

Comment: In general, you can't determine that - it's a function of the network configuration. However, as phrased currently, this will probably get closed as "trying to break the security of a specific system". You could possibly rephrase as "is it possible to attack a specific system which is behind a NAT configuration or similar", which could be more acceptable.

Comment: This really isn't a security question but a networking basics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a port forwarded to that specific computer that the attacker can use, such an attack wouldn't work. The attacker would have to do the reverse, making the victim computer connect to the attacker's computer.